# How Can I Find How Many Querystrings Are Used In A Webform

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

**Please help me any body..**

I want to write a method to find how many  querystrings are useing in a webform.

Actually i want to know how many querystrings are used in a webform and using with querystring count, i want to retrive the querystrings values.

Answer (score 0):

The [`QueryString` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) on the `HttpRequest` instance is of [type `NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx).  It has [a `Count` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase.count.aspx):

```
var numberOfQueryStringParameters = Request.QueryString.Count;
```

Comment: Hi David, i want to write a method to find out how many querystirngs are using in webforms and holds the querystring values into variables.

Comment: @BharathKumar: And where are you stuck?  The `Request.QueryString` object contains the query string key/value pairs.  You can get the information you need from that object.

Comment: i am getting the count of querystrings using like this for (int i = 0; i > Request.QueryString.Count; i++) { if (i > 0) { name = Request.QueryString[i]; } }                                                             then i want to retrive the count of  query string values into a variables.

Comment: @BharathKumar: And in what way does that not work for you?  (Other than the use of `Response.Write`, which is almost always a flaw in the design.)  It's very unclear what the issue is that you're facing.